# Convert nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to convert a datetime format column (example value: 12-11-2020 18:15:06) which is actually a nvarchar into this date format: yyyymmdd

This is what I tried so far but I'm getting the following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, why are you storing a date/time value as a string in the first place?  You should really fix your data!

Comment: We're on the same page, I'm not the DB owner and only have READ-ONLY access unfortunately. Just tagged SQL-SERVER

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You're casting as datetime, but formatting for just a date. Try changing 'datetime' to just 'date'.

Comment: Also, I don't believe `'YYYYMMDD'` is an accepted format. Check out this for options: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/

Comment: What is the datatype of the column MYDATE? Is it some type of string? If so, you probably have bigger problems to address.

Comment: Is `12-11-2020` December 11th or November 12th? If we don't know, how can SQL Server? See one of the (many!) problems with storing a date in the wrong data type?

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems here.

- Dates should not be stored as strings.

  - You lose the ability to perform any kind of date math or extract date parts.
  - You lose built-in validation (both invalid dates like February 31st and any garbage that doesn't even look like a date).
  - For example, we have no idea if `12-11-2020` is December 11th or November 12th, or if the data was entered consistently. Imagine a person from the US did some of the data entry and a colleague from Germany did the rest.
- `FORMAT()` is the most expensive way to format a date (see [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) and [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time) - these are articles about removing time altogether, but the overhead with `FORMAT()` is the same).
- An index on `MYDATE` can't be used to satisfy this query, so you will do a full table scan every time, which will get worse and worse as the table grows.

You can perform your query in your given scenario without changing anything, but I highly recommend you fix the column and make sure data entry can't be arbitrary (use a date picker or calendar control so *you* dictate a consistent format).

**If 12-11-2020 is December 11th**:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, MYDATE, 110) >= @DateVariable;
```

**If 12-11-2020 is November 12th**:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, MYDATE, 105) >= @DateVariable;
```

Note that this still might not get the *correct* and *logical* results if some people *thought* they entered December 11th and others *thought* they entered November 12th.

*You can see all the valid style numbers for CONVERT/TRY_CONVERT [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).*